# Access float value from astropy Distance object

Tags: python, astropy

I need to access the float value from the [Distance](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.2.1/_generated/astropy.coordinates.distances.Distance.html) astropy class.

Here'a a MWE:

```
from astropy.coordinates import Distance
from astropy import units as u

d = []
for _ in range(10):
    d.append(Distance(_, unit=u.kpc))
```

This results in a list of `<class 'astropy.coordinates.distances.Distance'>` objects:

```
[<Distance 0.0 kpc>, <Distance 1.0 kpc>, <Distance 2.0 kpc>, <Distance 3.0 kpc>, <Distance 4.0 kpc>, <Distance 5.0 kpc>, <Distance 6.0 kpc>, <Distance 7.0 kpc>, <Distance 8.0 kpc>, <Distance 9.0 kpc>]
```

I need to store the *floats* (not the objects) and I don't know how to access them. Since this MWE is part of a larger code, I can't just do `d.append(_)`. I need to access the floats from the objects generated by the `Distance` class.

Add:

I tried converting the list to a numpy array with:

```
np.asarray(d)
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Do you mean `x = Distance(_, unit=u.kpc) ;  d.append(x.kpc)` ?

Comment: That works @furas, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `value` attribute of the `Distance` objects.

```
d = []
for _ in range(10):
    d.append(Distance(_, unit=u.kpc).value)
```

...but then you might as well just use your variable `_` without instantiating those objects in the first place. Or maybe I'm misunderstood something.

Another way to put it:

```
>>> [i.value for i in d]
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know you could use the unit as well, as in furas's comment, but I guess that way... you need to know the unit.

Comment: This is correct, though the `Distance` class itself can have an array representation--it is very wasteful to create a list of many `Distance` objects in the same units.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, a `Distance` object can be like an array.  It's silly and wasteful to make a list of single `Distance` objects all of the same unit.  Instead you can do just

```
>>> dists = Distance(np.arange(10), unit=u.kpc)  # Note the use of a Numpy array
>>> dists
<Distance [ 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.] kpc>
```

Most other code should recognize that as a Numpy array and act accordingly.  Though if not, you can always do

```
>>> dists.value
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

To get a raw Numpy `ndarray` with the magnitudes in kpc.  Don't use a list of many `Distance` objects.  It is extremely wasteful!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
d = []
for _ in range(10):
    x = Distance(_, unit=u.kpc)
    d.append(x.kpc)  # x.Mpc , x.lightyear, etc.
```

or

```
d = []
for _ in range(10):
    d.append( Distance(_, unit=u.kpc).kpc ) # Distance(_, unit=u.kpc).lightyear
```